# Cant Access my EC2 Intance through IP

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

i have an website on wordpress, on an EC2 instance, with a ebs store, i access it using putty, and try to update the linux , cause its says updates where avaliable, it got a couple of errors in the process, and after that i couldn't access the website anymore, i check the instance status on my aws dashboard, and it says it could not be reached, try to reboot with no luck, then i stop it and start it, and works, both alerts was green, i try login with putty and works, however, when try to view the site using explorer it display a message "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" , i read that after stop/starting a instance some settings has to be applied again, but the elastic ip addres its still the same, and the connection rules are still there, i guess its a setting that i have to make, but i have no clue, thanks. in advance

pd: even the website does not display at all, the favicon its shown, i access the instance via ftp using filezilla and works, all my flies are there.

Comment: Did you re-associate the elastic IP with the instance after stopping and restarting the server?

Comment: after reading your answer i disassociate the elastic ip, and then associated back, still no changes

Comment: Perhaps you just need to restart Apache? Is it currently running?

Comment: wao, you just made it, i was missing that part, huge thanks, not works correctly, can i give points or something? or rate you?

Comment: i mean now its working correctly